# Java and Eclipse -- Replace `extends` and `super` with `returns` and `accepts`

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, wildcard

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I noticed recently with wildcards in Java, that...

`? super T` pretty much means `? accepts T`

and...

`? extends T` generally means `? returns T`.

Suppose I have a `List<? extends Cat>`. Is there ever a reason I'd declare this other than wanting to get a `Cat` out of it?  Or what about `LitterBox<? super Cat>`?  Would I ever declare such a thing unless I wanted to pass a `Cat` (or something that passes a `Cat`) into it?

So assuming that rationale holds...

Is there any way I could get Eclipse to both syntax highlight and auto-replace `accepts` and `returns` with `super` and `extends`?

Also, is there any reason besides "I'll have to regex my code before letting other people look at it" that this may not be a great idea?

Comment: Java is intentionally designed not to allow things like this.  You are looking at a lot of pain... Just learn the language properly.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Do I need to clarify?  Am I being offensive?  I've researched it, and such a convention is recommended in a lot of places... also, I've looked up how to do such a thing, to no avail...

Comment: Eclipse has the possibility to add replacement texts, where words you enter are replaced with something else.  Perhaps that would work, but probably only globally.

Comment: Hmm, could you give a link?  Google only yields "Find/Replace" Eclipse features.

Comment: The Eclipse term is "templates". http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-templates.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there are **plenty** of reasons why Oracle didn't make this a language feature, for example:

1. Two new reserved keywords;
2. `super` and `extends` pretty much exactly capture the meaning;
3. `accepts` and `returns` in those positions don't even have any sense; it may only be useful to **imagine** them there in order to help your general understanding. A type `T extends List` neither accepts, nor returns anything.

Comment: I'll run through your points.  1. Ok, I get it, but a little harsh?  2. Nothing constructive, you basically said "I disagree with your assumption" without any reasoning.  Why are accepts and returns any less valid?  I'm sure they could be, it's just that I'm asking why.
3. They do make sense, to the point that such a convention is actually advised by Oracle's documentation.  Suppose I have a `List<? extends Cat>`.  It's guaranteed to return `Cat` for all of it's generic return types, correct?  And if it's a `List<? super Cat>`, it's guaranteed to accept a cat for all it's generic parameters.

Comment: Points 2. and 3. are similar in that 2. claims the original keywords **do** capture the correct meaning and 3. claims that your alternative keywords **don't**. These are **arguments** why I disagree and not statements of disagreement. Consider this: a `List` is a **type**. It is not a **method** and methods are the ones that *accept* or *return* values. There is indeed no direct sense in the phrase "`List<? extends Cat` returns `Cat`s". The type does no such thing and its member methods **may or may not** do that.

Comment: I undownvoted, thanks for clarifying.  However, I disagree with the "may or may not" return/accept-- I can't think of a case you'd declare "extends" or "super" if you weren't actually passing in or pulling out something from the object.  Why declare a `List<? extends Cat>` if you're never pulling a cat out of it?  Why a `List<? super Cat>` if you're never passing a cat (or something that passes a cat) into it?

Comment: We agree on the usual way to use the type bounds. However, it would be inappropriate for the whole language to adopt keywords that work only for the typical use case. You may have a marker interface, for example, whose type parameter may only help transfer that type information via inference to some other point. At the type-theoretical level, these are just the upper and lower type bounds and the keywords follow that meaning pretty much exactly.

Comment: However, I consider the first point as actually the strongest one. Programming languages that put reserved keywords into the same namespace with general identifiers will always tend to maximally reuse the same keywords. If it had a Lispy or XML-ish syntax, then maybe Java would indeed use your terms.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Believe it or not (on a somewhat related note), I'm actually designing a statically typed DSL, and knowing if the syntax is valid is helpful in knowing how/if I'll want to do generics (...don't ask).

Answer (score 4):

> So is there any way I could get Eclipse to both syntax highlight and auto-replace accepts and returns with super and extends?

I imagine you could modify (i.e. hack) the Eclipse JDT editor to do this, but it wouldn't be simple.

> Also, is there any reason besides "I'll have to regex my code before letting other people look at it" that this may not be a great idea?

Isn't that enough?

What about:

- "I'll have to regex my code before the standard Java toolchain will understand it", or
- "It won't be Java anymore"?

> Or for that matter, any reason Oracle didn't make this a language feature?

Because there is no value to either Oracle, or the vast majority of Java developers in making gratuitous cosmetic changes to the language syntax.

---

Look, if you want to invent your own programming language, please feel free.  But suggesting disruptive changes to the Java language is ... frankly ... pointless.

---

> I wasn't asking for a "disruptive change", I was asking why they didn't use a similar syntax in the first place

You are asking the wrong people.  Ask "them".

Comment: Eh, jar hacking would definitely not be worth it.  I was thinking more along the lines of Eclipse scriptability, since I can imagine a way to do this with Xcode.

Sorry, I wasn't asking for a "disruptive change", I was asking why they didn't use a similar syntax in the first place (since it might be a good reason for me to not work with it now.) But I understand why that remark would have been construed that way (see above.)

As for the Java toolchain-- yeah, that's a pretty big problem...

But the second point-- what's wrong with that?

Comment: (Meta-question: why do so many SO Questions ask this kind of thing.  Do you guys really think that we are channelling Bill Gosling & his team?  Or that we can raid their filing cabinets / email archives from 20 years ago?)

Comment: *"But the second point-- what's wrong with that?"* - Ask your company's IT manager ...